# Will thread be disposed if an object sets to null

Tags: c#, multithreading, object, dispose

I have a class ClassA

```cs
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(EndlessLoop);
        t.IsBackground = True;
        t.Start();
    }

    private void EndlessLoop()
    {
        while (True)
        {
    // do something 
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm not sure if the thread will be disposed if I set ClassA object to null

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();

# will the thread exit ?
a = null;
```

Or maybe I should implement IDisposable, and call it manually?

Comment: I would add a bool variable shouldRun and set it to true.  Implement IDisposable and in the dispose method set shouldRun to false so the EndlessLoop can exit.

Answer (score 4):

Once started, the thread will terminate after the routine comes to an end (or `Thread.Abort` is invoked or the program exits). The `Thread` class doesn't implement `IDisposable` so there's no `Dispose` method to call. To terminate a long-running thread, you could set a flag that the thread checks periodically.

The `Thread` object is eligible to be garbage collected once it goes out of scope and is no longer referenced. However, the spawned thread will continue running.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing going to happen to the OS thread if you remove last refence to the `Thread` object corresponding to it - [C# Thread object lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699147/c-sharp-thread-object-lifetime). The thread will continue to run the code until the method finishes (unlikely in `while(true)` case shown), thread is terminated with `Abort` (don't do that - [What's wrong with using Thread.Abort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort)) or process ends.

The only good option is to somehow notify thread's code that it should finish (i.e. using events or even global variable protected by `lock`). Also consider if using `Task` and `async` with corresponding cancellation mechanism would simplify code (it would not solve infinite loop issue but give good framework to write cancellable operations).

Note that you can't "dispose" thread because it does not implement Dispose ([Do we need to dispose or terminate a thread in C# after usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698107/do-we-need-to-dispose-or-terminate-a-thread-in-c-sharp-after-usage)),